# Difficulties complying to coding standard for a coursera Python assignment

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I can't get the programming assignments to pass the autograder. I think I am missing some crucial information. Any help is welcome.

The error message is very generic and doesn't help me solve the  problems. In both cases:  "Your solution failed 2 test case(s). Please     try again. problem4_1.py"

I have tried different approaches. None works, although the result when I run the code through Spyder are identical to the ones given in the assignment (as you can verify in the Provide background tab). What am I missing???

Problem 4_1:
Write a function that will sort an alphabetic list (or list ofwords) into alphabetical order. Make it sort independently of whether the letters arecapital or lowercase. First print out the wordlist, then sort and print out the sorted list.
Here is my run on the list firstline below (note that the wrapping was added when I pasted it into the file -- this is really two lines in the output).

```
problem4_1(firstline)
['Happy', 'families', 'are', 'all', 'alike;', 'every', 'unhappy',           'family',
 'is', 'unhappy', 'in', 'its', 'own', 'way.', 'Leo Tolstoy', 'Anna Karenina']
['alike;', 'all', 'Anna Karenina', 'are', 'every', 'families', 'family',
'Happy', 'in', 'is', 'its', 'Leo Tolstoy', 'own', 'unhappy', 'unhappy', 'way.']

"""
```

My solution:
    problem 4_1
    #%%

```
def problem4_1(wordlist):
    """ Takes a word list prints it, sorts it, and prints the sorted    list 
"""

    print(firstline)
    firstline.sort(key=str.lower)
    print(firstline)
```

Comment: _Please try again. problem4_2.py_ and yet the question is about 4_1... is it a typo :P?

Comment: You could call it a typo. Originally I entered 2 problems: problem4_1 and problem 4_2. But the layout was not very readable. I deleted one of the problems. Both give me the same error message from the Coursera autograder. So I assume uI make the same kind of mistake.

Answer (score 0):

firstline isn’t defined in your function. It may be working in your manual operation because it’s accessing the global variable, but wouldn’t work as a standalone function. I think you want to be operating on wordlist within your function.

Comment: I changed the code to: def problem4_1(wordlist):
    """ Takes a word list prints it, sorts it, and prints the sorted list """
        
    print(wordlist)
    wordlist.sort(key=str.lower)
    print(wordlist)

Comment: From the question, I would interpret that you need to print the sorted list in the function. Before calling the function, print the unsorted list. The function should only have one print line in it.